# Rhino + Maven + Qunit Object with import property

Tags: javascript, maven, rhino, qunit

I have a strange problem and hope someone can help. I'm running headless JavaScript tests with Rhino and QUnit. So I execute my JS tests with Rhino executing RhinoShell in Qunit test class.

And in one of my JS files I have Object with it's own property import something like:

`MyObject.import("");` But I have to escape this or mock it in my tests. So I tried to mock it with my own object like:

```
MyObj = {
    import : function() {
    }
};
```

And locally with Rhino I have no problem doing this. But when I try to execute it with `maven` some kind of strict mode is enabled and throw error

```
: invalid property id import : function()...... and so on.
```

Please help me to mock this object I tried with `JsMockito` but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property name `import` is inadvertently flagged as a [reserved word](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/250), so use an alternative:

- Import
- $import
- _import

**References**

- [YUI Compressor Issue #250: YUI Compressor Runtime Error](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/250)